# Looping one array with another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays

1) `String[] images = {"#1","#2", "#3", "#4", "#5" };`

2) `String[] items = {"1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };`

The Items may vary , but the images array is fixed. I wan the output mapping like

```
 image 1 => item 1
 image 2 => item 2 
 image 3 => item 3
 image 4 => item 4
 image 5 => item 5
 image 1 => item 6
 image 2 => item 7
 image 3 => item 8
```

and so on.
My work around is as follows,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            for( int y=0;y< items.length;y++ ){
            for( int i=0;i< images.length;i++ ){

                if( y >= images.length ){
                    int remaining = items.length % images.length;
                    System.out.println("remaining..." + remaining);
                    for( int x=0;x<=remaining;x++ ){
                        System.out.println( "image" +images[x]+"=> item =>"+items[x]);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println( "image" +images[y]+"=> item =>"+items[y]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything. Loop over the longer array, and use the modulo (`%`) operator to generate the leftside index.

Comment: image 1,2,3 are mapped to more than one elements, that basically stops you from using a map implementation.

Comment: I tried it but nothing worked. I'll paste my work around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<items.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println(images[i%images.length] + " => " + items[i]);
}
```

`i%images.length` gives the rest of the division of `i`, i.e. your position in the `items` array, with the length of the `images` array. So `images[i%images.length]` loops through the `images` array.